# How to repeat a string 'x' amount of times in Livecode

Tags: livecode

I have a program which sets a variable "x" to the length of a random dictionary word, and then *should* put "a" into a field x amount of times. However I am unsure whether my syntax is right or wrong. The variable `randomword` is already defined and works. My non-working code is as follows:

```
    global x
    on mouseUp
        put length(randomword) into x
        put repeatedString("a",x) into field "wordDisplay"
    end mouseUp
```

However, when I look at wordDisplay after clicking my button, it is blank. An explanation of why, and code to fix this would be really beneficial.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if 'repeatedString' is a function you're calling from somewhere else, but if I understand what you're trying to do, you can try something like this, where you place 'a' into temporary variable:

```
put length(randomword) into x
repeat x
   put "a" after temp
end repeat
set text of field "wordDisplay" to temp
```

Also, am guessing this is the case, but the only reason to use the global is if you plan to use the value of x across the scripts of multiple objects. If you're just using 'x' in this script, you don't need the variable declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Page 227 of my book "Programming LiveCode for the Real Beginner" contains the following useful function, which does exactly what you want:

```
function repeatChar theChar,theAmount
  local myLongString
  set the itemDel to theChar
  put theChar into item theAmount of myLongString
  return myLongString
end repeatChar
```

Note that a repeat loop is not necessary.

Use the function in your script like this:

```
global randomWord
on mouseUp
    local x
    put length(randomWord) into x
    put repeatChar("a",x) into field "wordDisplay"
end mouseUp
```